# How do I run diagnostic plots for lmer in R?

Tags: r, diagnostics, lmer

I am trying to run diagnostic plots on an `lmer` model but keep hitting a wall. I'm not sure how much information I need to provide here, but here goes:

The model is simple:

```
best <- lmer(MSV_mm ~ Size_treat + (1|Rep) + (1|Patch) + (1|Trap), data= early_nopine).
```

`MSV_mm` is numeric (snout-vent lengths) and `Size_treat` is a factor with 4 levels: Continuous, Large, Medium and Small. `Rep`, `Patch` and `Trap` are random effects.

When I run `plot(best)`, I get the following error message:

```
"Error in as.double(y) : 
  cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'"
```

I assume this is related to the `lmer` function. I have trolled the web and have not yet found an answer to this problem. Is it an `lmer` thing?

Comment: I think you're assuming since you can run `plot` on a `lm` object, you can do that for a `lmer` object too. Note that there is a `plot.lm` but not a `plot.lmer` function.

Comment: @SeñorO They are assuming correctly: `?plot.merMod`.

Comment: @joran I don't have `plot.merMod` when I load `lme4`. Additionally, an `lmer` model goes into `plot.default` on my machine.

Comment: @SeñorO I didn't either, until I upgrade **lme4** to the most current version on CRAN.

Comment: @joran I would imagine that's OP's problem then - I get the same error (which comes from `xy.coords`)

Comment: Yes, wish I had a plot.lmer function. I updated my lme4 package and tried working with plot.merMod, but I'm still getting the same "cannot coerce S4 to vector" error message. Grrr...

Comment: Perhaps it's platform specific. I'm on OS X and as of lmer 1.0-4 I don't have a `plot.merMod`.

Comment: OK, I need a reproducible example.  With a fresh install of `lme4` 1.0-4 from CRAN, this works for me: `library(lme4); fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy); plot(fm1)`.  `plot.merMod` is not exported but you should be able to see it via `lme4:::plot.merMod`.  abbrv. `sessionInfo()`: r-devel r63889, 32-bit linux, lme4_1.0-4 ; Matrix_1.0-14  ; lattice_0.20-23 ; compiler_3.1.0 ; grid_3.1.0 ; MASS_7.3-29 ; minqa_1.2.1 ; nlme_3.1-111 ; splines_3.1.0 ; tools_3.1.0

Comment: I'll say it again in case it got lost in the wordy command above: `plot.merMod` is not exported but you should be able to see it via `lme4:::plot.merMod`.  Does `lme4:::plot.merMod(best)` work?

Comment: Just checked, this also works for me on 64-bit linux, R 2.15.3, with a fresh CRAN install

Comment: @KikaTarsi: if you just updated, what version do you have now?

Comment: Ah haaa, you were right, had to update. Just got 1.0.4. Using plot.merMod(best) didn't work--it couldn't find the function. But now plot(best) gives me my residuals, which is a start

Answer (score 8):

I can reproduce this error with `lme4.0`, which is equivalent to earlier (pre-1.0.0) versions of `lme4` from CRAN.  If you use an up-to-date `lme4` from CRAN (version 1.0-4 as of October 2013), this is what should happen:

```
library(lme4)
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
plot(fm1)
```

[image]

Although `plot.merMod` is not exported, it is documented (`?plot.merMod`), and you can see it via `lme4:::plot.merMod` (or `getAnywhere("plot.merMod")`).

If you want to reproduce this plot with an earlier version of `lme4`, you can do:

```
augData <- data.frame(sleepstudy,fitted=fitted(fm1),resid=residuals(fm1))
library(lattice)
xyplot(fitted~resid,data=augData)
```

You should think about whether you want deviance residuals (the default from `residuals()`) or Pearson residuals (the default for `plot.merMod`).